# Undefined object when sending a JSON object from Express server into React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am new to React and Express. I had created client side on port 8080 with **localhost:8080/site3** route:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Site3 extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('FETCHING');
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/site3', {
      method: "GET"
    })
      .then(res => {
        res.json();
      })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        console.log('Finished fetching');
      });
  }

  render() {
    return content;
  }
}
```

and server side on port 3000:

```
const express = require("express");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();

const data = [
  { id: "tt0110357", name: "The Lion King", genre: "animation" },
  { id: "tt0068646", name: "The Godfather", genre: "crime" },
  { id: "tt0468569", name: "The Dark Knight", genre: "action" }
];

app.get("/site3", (req, res) => {
  console.log("RESPONDING");
  res.send(data);
});

// Port 3000
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Service 2 listening on port ${process.env.PORT}!`)
);
```

After starting both React and Express server, I went to the **localhost:8080/site3**. 
The Express server had **get** the request from the client, printed `RESPONDING` and sent a JSON data back to React.
But the React cannot get the JSON data and return to `undefined` object.

[image]

How do I solve this?

Comment: instead of `res.send()` try `res.json()`

Comment: @kiro Can you check api response in network tab or attache the screen here?

Comment: Most probably the issue on React side where you are holding response, but in first then block you are not returning anything thats why you wont get result in necxt then block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

return statement is missing in the res.json() call.

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('FETCHING');
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/site3', {
      method: "GET"
    })
      .then(res => {
       return res.json();
      })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        console.log('Finished fetching');
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leave the curly brackets from the first .then() like the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('FETCHING');
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/site3', {
      method: "GET"
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        console.log('Finished fetching');
      });
  }
```